# Binding TwinColSelect in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

How can I bind entity to TwinColSelect in Vaadin ? I can do that for simple components (TextField, ComboBox), but I do not know, how to do that for TwinColSelect component. I receive a compilation problem on commented line. SelectedString attribute in ExampleEntity should contains all selected elements from TwinColSelect.

```
import com.vaadin.data.Binder;
import com.vaadin.navigator.View;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringView;
import com.vaadin.ui.TwinColSelect;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@SpringView(name = "example")
public class Example extends VerticalLayout implements View {
    public Example() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("item1");
        list.add("item2");
        ExampleEntity entity = new ExampleEntity();

        Binder<ExampleEntity> binder = new Binder<>(ExampleEntity.class);
        TwinColSelect<String> twinColSelect = new TwinColSelect<>("strings");
        twinColSelect.setItems(list);
        twinColSelect.setRows(twinColSelect.getRows());

//        binder.bind(twinColSelect, ExampleEntity::getSelectedStrings, ExampleEntity::setSelectedStrings); //TODO ?
        binder.readBean(entity);

        addComponent(twinColSelect);
    }

    private class ExampleEntity {
        private List<String> selectedStrings;

        public List<String> getSelectedStrings() {
            return selectedStrings;
        }
        public void setSelectedStrings(List<String> selectedStrings) {
            this.selectedStrings = selectedStrings;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to bind it. Since it is representing a 1:n relaction which must be read/persisted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding with `binder` is always based on the type of the `setValue` method of the target component. For `TwinColSelect<String>`,  the value type is `Set<String>`. To be able to bind that to a bean property of the type `List<String>`, you need to supply a converter that converts between `List` and `Set`.

To set a converter, you can do the binding like this:

`binder.forField(twinColSelect)
  .<List<String>> withConverter(ArrayList::new, HashSet::new)
  .bind(ExampleEntity::getSelectedStrings, ExampleEntity::setSelectedStrings);`

Note that in this case you need to define the generic type for the `withConverter` method because otherwise, the compiler would require the getter to be defined to return `ArrayList<String>` instead of the more generic `List<String>`.

Comment: I did not know, that TwinColSelect<String> has the value Set. I just need to change attribute type in entity from List to String.  Thanks (y)